# How to insert flutter splash screen before this sign up page. I think I'm missing some codes

Tags: android, flutter, dart, splash-screen

Does anybody know how to add a flutter splash screen before this sign-in page? I have coded using this [github file](https://github.com/Rapid-Technology/flutter_splash_screen/blob/master/lib/main.dart). and [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQB1E2JLZJA).  think I'm missing some parts of the codes.it doesn't display. for the login screen, I watch a different video and it's successfully implemented. but now I want to add the splash screen before this login screen appears.

[image]

> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'loginScreen.dart';
import 'dart:async';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Login UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:LoginScreen(),




    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // logo here
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/logo.png',
              height: 120,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

> loginScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  bool isRememberMe =false;

  Widget buildEmail() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Email',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight:
              FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 6,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                  )
                ]
            ),

            height: 60,
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.email,
                    color: Color(0xff53bf87),
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
            )
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildPassword() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Password',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight:
              FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 6,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                  )
                ]
            ),

            height: 60,
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.lock,
                    color: Color(0xff5ac18e),
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
            )
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildForgotPassBtn(){

    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => print("Forget Password pressed"),
        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:0),
        child: Text(
          'Forgot Passsword?',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight : FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildRememberCb(){
    return Container(

      height: 20,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor :Colors.white),
            child:Checkbox(
              value: isRememberMe, onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  isRememberMe =value!;
                });
            },
              checkColor: Colors.green,
              activeColor: Colors.white,

            ),
          ),

          Text(
            'Remember me',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildLoginBtn(){
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:25),
      width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedButton(
          elevation:5,
          onPressed: ()=> print ('login pressed'),
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(15),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder (
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)

          ),
           color: Colors.white,
          child: Text(
            'LOGIN',

          style:TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff5ac18e),
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          Color(0x665ac18e),
                          Color(0x995ac18e),
                          Color(0xcc5ac18e),
                          Color(0xff5ac18e),
                        ]
                    )
                ),

                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 25,
                    vertical: 120,
                  ),

                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Sign In',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 40,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 50),
                      buildEmail(),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      buildPassword(),
                      buildForgotPassBtn(),
                      buildRememberCb(),
                      buildLoginBtn(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the flutter native splash package

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'loginScreen.dart';
import 'dart:async';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Login UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashScreen(),




    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // logo here
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/logo.png',
              height: 120,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

that also eliminates the white screen when launching the app. Just add the dependency into your yaml like this:[image]

to then create the splash screen add something like this into your yaml file as well

[image]

Then you just run the following command in your terminal:

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

and that should be it

Comment: Avoid using imagery code. It's much better to hardcode the codes directly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, it should be noted that while the Flutter framework is loading, there will be a blank white screen.  I maintain a package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) that can be used to replace the default white screen with a splash screen.  You may find that is easier than implementing a splash screen manually.